# My Brilliant Padlet

Tags: notation

If a ∈ (0,4), what is the value of a? is it between 0 to 4 but not 0 or 4?

Comment: $($ for exclusive, $[$ for inclusive.

Comment: $\in$ read "in", i.e. "it belongs to". Thus $1 \in (0,4)$ is true because the number $1$ belongs to the interval $(0,4)$ ($0$ and $4$ are excluded) while $0 \notin (0,4)$.

Comment: $a\in (0, 4) \Longleftrightarrow (a \in {\mathbb R} \text{ and } 0 < a \text{ and } a < 4)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $\in$ symbol means that the element before it belongs to some **set**. A better example would be $2\in \mathbb{N}$. This means that the number two is a natural number.

$(a,b)$ in the other hand means an open interval which includes all the real numbers that are greater than $a$ but less than $b$ but not equal to them. So you are correct. When $a\in (0,4)$ a is an element of that interval. The expression is equivalent to saying that $0 < a < 4$ and that a is a real number ($a\in \mathbb{R}$).

Additionally when $(a,b)$ means an open interval, $[a,b]$ means a closed interval and in this case it's the same as $(a,b)$ but it also includes $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 1):

That symbol means: "is a member of...", or "belongs to".  It is often used to state that a particular element is a member of a set.

Answer (score 1):

$\in$ means "is an element of". This means $a$ is a number such that $0<a<4$.

Answer (score 1):

$\in$, which has the telling $\TeX$-command `\in`, is used to show that something is an element of some set. In your case, $a\in (0,4)$ means that $a$ is some member of the set $(0,4)$.

So what is $(0,4)$? It is the set of numbers between $0$ and $4$, not counting $0$ or $4$ themselves. This is called an *open interval*. Open because it doesn't contain any end points, and interval because it is a contiguous set of numbers, with no holes.

In contrast, $[0,4]$ would be the set of numbers between $0$ and $4$, *including* $0$ and $4$. It is called a *closed* interval. In-between you have $[0,4)$ and $(0,4]$, which are both called half-closed or half-open intervals, depending on what you feel like.